# Putting the runtime value of Opacity in DoubleAnimation.From in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, styles

Just trying to put the "current" value of Opacity in the DoubleAnimation.From. I've looked thoroughly but have not found an answer yet.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type mr:MRWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type mr:MRWindow}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation From="[I want the value (when the animation begins) of the opacity of MRWindow (that this style is applied to)]" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" ...../>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      <OtherThings Here ...../>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *don't set* the `From` property. Then the animation will start at the current property value.

See the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.from.aspx) on how the animation behaves when you only set the `To` property:

> The animation progresses from the animated property's base value or a
>   previous animation's output value to the value specified by the To
>   property

Comment: what about the DoubleAnimationUsingKeyframes? There's a Value property in each Keyframe, no From To or By. Is there a way to get the same result as By?

Comment: That is a different question... And how about just giving it a try?

Comment: I didn't even think about asking the question before trying many times. I can perfectly do what I want in code, but I think xaml is the better place for what I want, and hence the question after so many tries.
Thanks.

Comment: @mr992: `what about the DoubleAnimationUsingKeyframes? There's a Value property in each Keyframe, no From To or By. Is there a way to get the same result as By?` - this is a separate question that does not related to the answer of @Clemens. About this was not said in your original question. You need to ask a new question, and not to ask it in the comments.

Comment: Actually, the question should have been about how to represent different storyboard implementations in xaml instead of in code.
Sorry, and much thanks.